# Query returns non-existent literal value

Tags: informix

On `Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10.FC5WE` I observe a strange behavior where a query returns a result, but shouldn't. I reduced the problem to the following example as best as I could; the example *is* brittle...

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE xxx_main (foo INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);
CREATE TEMP TABLE xxx_sub (foo INT NOT NULL); -- Notice: No PRIMARY KEY
INSERT INTO xxx_main (foo) VALUES (1);
-- Notice that `sub` remains empty

SELECT sub1.bar -- The literal from the subquery; but since `sub1` has no rows, it should be `NULL`
FROM xxx_main
LEFT JOIN (SELECT xxx_sub.foo,
                  "foobar" AS bar
           FROM xxx_sub) AS sub1 ON sub1.foo = xxx_main.foo
LEFT JOIN xxx_sub AS sub2 ON sub2.foo = xxx_main.foo
WHERE xxx_main.foo = 1
AND sub1.foo IS NULL
```

My expectation for the query is to return a single row with `NULL` as the only column.

The actual result is one row with a value of `"foobar"`, which is the literal value from the `sub1` subquery. But `sub1` can't have any values, because the filter `sub1.foo IS NULL` prevents any rows from being joined, and `sub` being empty anyway. So where is `"foobar"` coming from? Am I confusing myself?

Even more puzzling: Modifying the query or the table layout in ways that should not have any effect causes the query to yield the expected result. Among other things, I observed this when removing the `sub2`-join in the query, defining `sub.foo` as a primary key in the table definition (with `sub` remaining empty), adding a (useless) `GROUP BY`-subquery, modifying the name `foo AS oof` in the subquery, and any arithmetic in the subquery (`xxx_sub.foo + 1`). All this leads me to believe that this is a SQL-compiler/-optimizer bug in `Informix`...

Comment: I was able to reproduce this with your reproduction on an Informix 14.10.FC1 server running on Linux (RHEL 7.4).  I've created a bug, CQ idsdb00110742, for this.  (I'll be checking a newer version after I've built it, but I suspect it is still present in the current versions.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is the bug tracker public?

Comment: No — but you can use the number when consulting with Tech Support.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If this is a genuine bug and not an error in expectations by me, we can close the question here on SA. Care to confirm?

Comment: After some issues with 'false positives' on build errors (warnings that were treated as errors), I can confirm that, at the moment, the problem reproduces in the next version of Informix 14.10 (14.10.FC9) too.  I note, for completeness, that I was testing with a database with buffered logging.  (I don't know if that affects the brittleness of the repro — it worked OK AFAICS.)  However, at the moment, the bug has neither been assigned nor had its "incoming defect" status changed to confirmed.

Comment: Yes, we probably could close the bug.  The question is "what's the best way to do that?"  I could write an answer, which you might accept — I'd make it 'community wiki' if I did.  That leaves the question visible to future visitors.  The alternative is to delete the question — which means the information will be lost to those in the future.  Thoughts?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think as far as SA is concerned, the relevant part of the question is if this is an error in my expectations or not. If you can outline as an answer to the question that my expectations wrt the SQL semantics are correct, yet Informix is misbehaving, then this question is asked and answered. I'd be nice for future visitors to leave a reference towards what the fate of this had been; that is if this *is* a defect or a WONTFIX quirk

Comment: I'll add a non-CW answer explaining that but it won't be immediately; I need to pretend to get some work done (though I did clean up the cause of the "false positives", so some useful work got done).

Comment: And I see I said ["close the bug"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72447576/query-returns-non-existent-literal-value?noredirect=1#comment128014239_72447576) when I meant "close this question" — sorry, auto-pilot kicked into gear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245240/discussion-between-user2722968-and-jonathan-leffler).